# How do I guarantee that utf-8 characters are scraped accurately using CURL in php?

Tags: utf-8, curl, screen-scraping

I am scraping webpages (using php's curl) that have accented characters (like "é").
In the source of those webpages, those characters are written using utf-8 (they are not html encoded.)

However, when the result is produced using the following code, I get question marks instead of the accented characters.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$file = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The header info returned from the scraped webpage indicates that the Content is set to "html/text."  There's no indication that it's utf-8 encoded.  I've tried using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER curl option to change the text encoding, but that doesn't do anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, first of all, are you sure the problem is not with the file editor you are using to open your file, that does not recognize the encoding properly ? Or with the webpage inside of which you are displaying the results ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer to my question, have a look at 
[characters changed in a Curl request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277552/characters-changed-in-a-curl-request)

The answer Dominic Rodger just saved my day with his reply..