# characters changed in a Curl request

Tags: encoding, curl

When I look at the XML data feed i get with the below code, special characters are correct in the XML code.
However when Curl returns the data, characters like "ó" and "ä" are converted into resp. "Ã³" and "Ã¤".
This conversion happens to all special characters, these 2 are just an example.

```
$myvar = curl_init();
$myURL = "http://someurl.com/";
curl_setopt($myvar, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2")]');
curl_setopt($myvar, CURLOPT_URL, $myURL);
curl_setopt($myvar, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($myvar, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($myvar, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,3);
$xmlstr = curl_exec ($myvar);
```

The header of the XML file says to encode as follows "?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?"

All I want is to get the same characters to show up in the Curl result without any transformation.

Hoping i just missed some plain easy step, looking forward to any answers.

Best regards
Fons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you know `$xmlstr` contains the wrong bytes? If you're looking at the output in a terminal window of some sort, it's probable that the problem is that the terminal does not support UTF-8, not that cURL is broken.

cURL doesn't care about UTF-8 or any other character encoding - its job is just to fetch a sequence of bytes from somewhere. It's not likely to be doing anything that will mangle special characters. If there's something wrong with the way you're using cURL, it'll be mangling everything, not just non-ASCII characters.

Comment: When i use echo $xmlstr and look in the sourcefile the characters are coverted.

I use 
<pre><code><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"></code></pre> as header for the output (html)

your suggestion is change that? than i would be very happy to know what header to use instead.

regards
Fons

Comment: Try adding `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` at the top of your `<head>...</head>` section.

Comment: you just saved my day!!
works like expected and now i dont have the funny "Ã³" and "Ã¤" anymore.
Just can slam myself in the head for this.
As this a local website i did not care about any meta tags in the header, where i use a default set for external pages.

Many thanks, you just gave me a workless weekend !

Best regards
Fons